# Sava data from bootstrap javascript modal to database

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap javascript **modal** and added to it two text inputs now what i want is to receive values from these inputs and save it to the database i think it could be done using jquery but i don't know how so i appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

```
<a  href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-info offset4" data-toggle="modal">Post New Job</a>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Add Job Details</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Position Name: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
    <p>Description: <textarea id="TextArea1" runat="server"></textarea></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="btnClose" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server">Close</button>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to expand on your question a little bit more. What backend technology are you using? Web Forms? ASP.Net MVC? Web API?

jQuery is a client side library, it can't communicate with the DB directly, unless you are going to be saving to the local store.

Comment: I am using web forms and yes i know that jquery doesn't communicate directly to the database and maybe there would be any way to pass data filled in these inputs either by sending them from javascript variables to the page of code behind or by using hidden fields, as i am new to javascript so i can't handle this issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for expanding.

There are a number of ways that you could accomplish passing the data back to the server.  Looking at the snippet of code you have posted I see that there is no form.  I'm guessing that there is no form even on the parent document?

You could use an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call, to send the data to a method on the code behind page;
Javascript

```
function sendData(){
    var positionName = $("").val(),
        department = $("".val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your-url.aspx/SaveData",
        data: "{'postionName': " + JSON.stringify(positionName) + ","
              + "'department': " + JSON.stringify(department) + "}"
    }).done(function(){
       alert("Data Saved");
    });
}
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public void SaveData(string positionName, string department)
{
    SaveNewData(positionName, department);
}
```

This a quick a dirty example but it might point you in the right direction.